# R: How I can check that my characters in one column have same value in another column

Tags: r, duplicates, equality

I am a beginner in R, and I need to learn how to perform code. As you can see in my data frame, I want to check whether the egg in column commodity has the same unit in all rows.

data frame:

```
df <- structure(list(commodity = c("eggs", "lentils (green)", "oil (vegetable)", 
"rice", "sugar (white)", "eggs", "lentils (green)", "oil (vegetable)", 
"rice", "sugar (white)", "eggs"), unit = c("1.8 kg", "900 g", 
"810 g", "kg", "kg", "1.8 kg", "900 g", "810 g", "kg", "kg", 
"1.8 kg")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -11L))

         commodity   unit
1             eggs 1.8 kg
2  lentils (green)  900 g
3  oil (vegetable)  810 g
4             rice     kg
5    sugar (white)     kg
6             eggs 1.8 kg
7  lentils (green)  900 g
8  oil (vegetable)  810 g
9             rice     kg
10   sugar (white)     kg
11            eggs 1.8 kg
```

I do not know what I should do

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I want to know, for example, Whether eggs have the same unit in all rows. And also other items.

Comment: can you share the expected output?

Answer (score 1):

One way could be:
First create a column with your units extracting only alphabetic letters, then use `distinct()`:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  mutate(unit1 = gsub("[^a-zA-Z]", "", unit)) %>% 
  distinct(unit1)
```

```
  unit1
1    kg
2     g
```

```
df <- structure(list(commodity = c("eggs", "lentils (green)", "oil (vegetable)", 
"rice", "sugar (white)", "eggs", "lentils (green)", "oil (vegetable)", 
"rice", "sugar (white)", "eggs"), unit = c("1.8 kg", "900 g", 
"810 g", "kg", "kg", "1.8 kg", "900 g", "810 g", "kg", "kg", 
"1.8 kg")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -11L))
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I want to know, for example, Whether eggs have the same unit in all rows. And also other items.

Answer (score 1):

In `base R`, we could use

```
length(unique(trimws(df$unit, whitespace = "[0-9.]+\\s+"))) == 1
[1] FALSE
```

If it is to check on a subset of elements

```
with(df, length(unique(trimws(unit[grepl("eggs", commodity)], 
    whitespace = "[0-9.]+\\s+"))) == 1)
[1] TRUE
```

---

If we want to check for all elements

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df %>% 
  group_by(item = str_extract(commodity, "^\\w+(?=\\s*)")) %>% 
  summarise(isUnitSame = n_distinct(str_extract(unit, "[a-z]+$"))==1)
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 5 × 2
  item    isUnitSame
  <chr>   <lgl>     
1 eggs    TRUE      
2 lentils TRUE      
3 oil     TRUE      
4 rice    TRUE      
5 sugar   TRUE
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I want to know, for example, Whether eggs have the same unit in all rows. And also other items.